# How to find a string from a line and delete the whole line

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Tooltip :

```
var ToolTip ="\nFilling :MLB\nInlay/onlay :BOL\nCaries :FIL";
```

the `\n` in the string makes the string to shift to new line:
I want than when i find string `Filling` a want to delete whole line ie `\nFilling :MLB`

I can find the string by using `indexOf` but how to delete the whole line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var ToolTip ="\nFilling :MLB\nInlay/onlay :BOL\nCaries :FIL";
ToolTip = ToolTip.replace(/\nFilling.*?\n/, '')
```